# :hover overrides :active styles - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a simple buy button:

```css
.btn {
  font-family: "IRANSansWeb";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9672fb, #d772fb);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: white;

  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
  transition: 0.2s;

}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
  <div class="spinner center">
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn submit" id="submit-pay" type="submit" value="BUY" />
</div>
```

Note that there is no movement (transform and box-shadow change) when we click on the button, right?

If I remove the hover style I get those desired movements:

```css
.btn {
  font-family: "IRANSansWeb";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9672fb, #d772fb);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: white;

  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
  transition: 0.2s;

}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn:not(.disabled):hover {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
  <div class="spinner center">
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn submit" id="submit-pay" type="submit" value="BUY" />
</div>
```

How can I have both active and hover animations on the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception) to override other styles:

```css
.btn {
  font-family: "IRANSansWeb";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9672fb, #d772fb);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: white;

  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
  transition: 0.2s;

}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(5px) !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
  <div class="spinner center">
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn submit" id="submit-pay" type="submit" value="BUY" />
</div>
```

If you don't want to use `!important`, you can try:

```css
.btn {
  font-family: "IRANSansWeb";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9672fb, #d772fb);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: white;

  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
  transition: 0.2s;

}


.btn:hover {
  transform: translateY(1px);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
  <div class="spinner center">
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn submit" id="submit-pay" type="submit" value="BUY" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at other wired question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733000/exclude-hover-on-element-when-its-parent-node-has-disabled-class

Comment: @SaraRee Sure. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

`:hover` applies when the mouse is pointing to the element.

`:active` applies when the mouse button is being clicked (so `:hover` is a prerequisite).

You can't make it `:active` without it also being `:hover`ed. (That simplifies somewhat as you can activate with the keyboard).

---

See [the spec on The Cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

> Sort rules with the same importance and origin by specificity of selector

Your rules have equal specificity and importance.

> Finally, sort by order specified

You specified `:hover` **after** `:active` so the `:hover` rules **override** the `:active` rules.

Define them the other way around so that the `:active` rules override the `:hover` rules.